Use schema_of_json() combined with from_json()
I'm using Spark SQL to unnest JSON strings. First, I want to hydrate JSON string column 'value' into a STRUCT type.
SELECT 
  from_json(value, schema_of_json(value))
FROM my_table

This raises an exception:
The input schema "schema_of_json(value)" is not a valid schema string. The input expression must be string literal and not null. SQLSTATE: 42K07

According to the documentation, the schema argument in from_json() can take an invocation of schema_of_json(). However the documentation doesn't demonstrate the two functions used together.
I've also tried:

Using the equivalent pyspark.sql,functions, with the same problem.
Using the notation value:object_name to access nested values. However I still need to hydrate to a complex type to perform operations such as explode().


You have provided a string column reference in the sql.  The error message is clear that it needs to be a string literal i.e. something in quotes.  The reason for this is that the type of any expression must be fixed before the start of any sql.  Row 1 vs Row 5 might have different schemas.
You can also specify a DDL schema directly if you know it.

Yes - I've successfully used the from_json() function with a DDL string. Unfortunately that doesn't allow schema evolution. I want to use dynamic invocation so new columns aren't lost in future.
I understand your point that each row can have a different schema. However this method doesn't work with schema_of_json_agg() either - which collects the schema for all records.
The documentation explicitly says "schema: A STRING expression or invocation of schema_of_json function". However in reality it appears that only a string expression is supported.
